# How do I morph a player's character to a specified player's character?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a shapeshift command that you can run via chat. It works pretty similar to how HD Admin handles character morphin (https://create.roblox.com/marketplace/asset/13549366436)

I know how to get the model a specified player's avatar by using `HumanoidDescription`. However, I want to **make a new rig with the specified avatar**. The reason I want to do this is so that I can **put a" animation** during the command. How do I do this?

Code (Simplified)

````
{
            PrimaryAlias = "shapeshift",
            SecondaryAlias = "change",
            PermissionLevel = 0,
            Function = function(player: Player, args: { string })
                local TemporaryRig = game.ReplicatedStorage.Rig.R15:Clone()
                TemporaryRig.Parent = game.Workspace
                
                

                game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
                    TemporaryRig.Position = player.Character.Position -- Main Problem
                        local id = PlayerService:GetUserIdFromNameAsync(args[1])
                        print(id .. " returned when GetUserIdFromNameSync") -- Debug
                        print(args[1] .. " returned") -- Debug
                    local newHumanoidDescription = game.Players:GetHumanoidDescriptionFromUserId(id)
                    TemporaryRig.Humanoid:ApplyDescription(newHumanoidDescription)
                end)
                end,
        },
```
````